# Interface segregation example C++

Tags: c++, solid-principles

I was looking at [oodesign website](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html) for interface segregation example

I understood the example and wrote below code in C++,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IWorkable {
public: 
    virtual void work() = 0;
};

class IFeedable{
public:
    virtual void eat() = 0;
};

// interface segregation principle - good example
class IWorker : public IFeedable, public IWorkable {
};

class Worker : public IWorkable, public IFeedable
{
public:
    void work() {
        cout << "working" <<endl;
    }

    void eat() {
        cout << "eating in launch break" <<endl;
    }
};

class SuperWorker : public IWorkable, public IFeedable{
public:
    void work() {
        cout << "working much more" << endl;
    }
    void eat() {
        cout << "eating in launch break" <<endl;
    }
};

class Robot :public IWorkable{
public:
    void work() {
        cout << "Robot working" <<endl;
    }
};

class Manager {
    IWorkable *worker;

public :
    void setWorker(IWorkable *w) {
        worker = w;
    }

    void manage() {
        worker->work();
    }
};

int main()
{
    IWorkable * w1 = new Worker();
    IWorkable * sw1 = new SuperWorker();
    IWorker *w2;
    Manager m1;
    m1.setWorker(w1);
    m1.manage();

    //When worker wants he can eat
    w2 = dynamic_cast<IWorker*>(w1);
    w2->eat();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run above code I get segmentation fault at  `w2->eat();`

My guess is code is casting only pointer of `IWorkable` to `IWorker` which won't work because `IWorkable` doesn't have `eat` method.

If so what would be the solution in this case ?
Any suggestion/pointer would help.

**Note**: I am trying it in C++98 however I am open to learn new way in C++11/14/17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dynamic_cast` is `return`ing `NULL` since `Worker` doesn't inherit `IWorker`.  By using the inheritance I assume you were going for, this works correctly.

```
class Worker : public IWorker { /* your same implmenetations */ };
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Yes, it works after I change as you suggested. It also works if I change it to `IFeedable *w2 = dynamic_cast<IFeedable*>(w1);`

Comment: I should have added null check for pointer before using that would have explained it.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the pointer `w2` without assigning it. Since a pointer value defaults to an undefined value, there is no guarantee that it points to a valid object. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers

Comment: has the question been updated after your answer? It seems to be assigned

Comment: Thank you for reply. `w1` is not deleted yet so `w2` is pointing to same as `w1` so I think in this case it is fine. @AlessandroTeruzzi no it is not updated after answer.